# PHP FPM Nginx unable to upload more than 2 GB of file

Tags: php, nginx, upload, limit, fpm

I am using a 64 BIT CENT OS with php 5.6 and with nginx/php fpm.

I am running a owncloud instance in the VPS and everything is running smoothly, except to the fact that any file which is more than 2 GB in size is not getting uploaded and gets a gateway error, I tweaked all the settings as said in

https://github.com/owncloud/documentation/wiki/Uploading-files-up-to-16GB

All the values are set, still whenever php-fpm writes the file to the temp directory, it stops exactly at 2 GB, sometimes 2.1 or 2.2 but not after that, it is not time out issue as sometimes if i upload 7 GB of file, it uploads for hours and progress bar goes without any issue till 100 % and then stops, checking in tmp folder i could see,

cd /var/www/owncloud/temp/

[root@files temp]# ll -ah

-rw-------  1 nginx nginx 2.2G Feb  9 17:46 phpyHKRQD

I am super confused here, as why php would stop at 2 GB in a 64 BIT environment.

Answer (score 1):

For very large files it's better to implement an chunked uploader. That is much better.

There are a lot of cool libs to solve your problem.

http://www.plupload.com/

upload a bit file completely can cause a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a 32 bit PHP installed on your 64 bit system.  You can check it by running

```
php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'
```

My 64 bit arch, but 32 bit PHP echos `2147483647` and my 64 bit arch with 64 bit PHP echos `9223372036854775807`

Comment: I get, php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'
9223372036854775807

Comment: What's the size of your TEMP filesystem?  `/var/www/owncloud/temp/`?

Comment: There's a setting called "Maximum upload size" in the web ui under Admin. Did you change that?

Comment: there is no restriction in that temp  location as I created that location manually and edited the configuration files to use that, tried editing the maximum upload size settings in the admin section to 8 GB still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, the issue is resolved.

Actually I missed to set  the setting,

fastcgi_request_buffering off

as said in,
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_files/big_file_upload_configuration.html

Now files greater than 2 GB gets uploaded.